# How to convert an integer to data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

After few operations I have

Integer `y = 4043   11 4043   12 4043   15`

I want to make it a data frame and transform it to two columns as following.

```
Voltage  Current
   4043       11
   4043       12
   4043        5
```

How do I do this?

Comment: So, it was the final output you wanted in your previous question.

Comment: You want to a convert vector to data.frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help :

```
y = c(4043,   11, 4043,   12, 4043,   15)

y.matrix = matrix(data = y, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,] 4043   11
# [2,] 4043   12
# [3,] 4043   15


y.df = as.data.frame(y.matrix)
# V1 V2
# 1 4043 11
# 2 4043 12
# 3 4043 15
```

Comment: `data.frame(matrix(y,ncol = 2, byrow = T ))`